# How can I install a python 3 module for its use in QGIS3 in Windows?

Tags: qgis-3, python-3

I've been struggling to install BeautifulSoup4 for a Python script I want to share with Windows users, but I just can't get it installed for its use in QGIS,
I've tried

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

and using the `ez_setup.py`

in the OSGeo4W, but `python --version` shipped with osgeo4w is 2.7.14 (latest osgeo4w release), while QGIS uses python 3, so I can't even use pip3 because osgeo4w shell is 2.7.14;

```
Script works good on linux.
```

Comment: you need set your python env using qgis python version,using a .bat for example